# how to check radius of 10 meter from x,y position - from GPS

Tags: c#, gps

i have this position from GPS:

40.715192,-74.005795

how to check if i in the range of 10 meter radius ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Haversine formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Pseudocode:

```
R = 6371; // corrected earth radius, km
dLat = degToRad(lat2-lat1);
dLon = degToRad(lon2-lon1); 
a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) +
        cos(degToRad(lat1)) * cos(degToRad(lat2)) * 
        sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2); 
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)); 
distance = R * c;
```

`degToRad` converts degress to radians, see e.g. [here](http://www.krellinst.org/uces/archive/resources/trig/node10.html)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and found this: 
http://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/haversine-formula-in-c/